# Confused with NSButton Image

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I have a square NSButton and an Image the same size of the button. I set the image to the button, turned off bordered and set scaling to none. Then the image seems smaller than the button. If I set scaling to axes independent, the image can fill the all button. But is set button enable to false. The button disappeared. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Your description, IMHO, is a bit confused! Anyway, for what I understood, you're having problem with Xcode.

You have to set the scaling because the button is always a bit larger than its content, because of the border (even if you turn off its borders, it will still be rendered with a small invisible border). For an unknown reasons, setting to Axes Independently solves this problem and resizes the image in the correct way (this works in any kind of NSControl you can use).

I cannot figure out how enabling or disabling the button can influences its visibility. Are you sure you're not using the "Hidden" property instead of the "Enabled" one?

```
[myButton setHidden:YES]
```

This will make the button transparent and insensible to clicks.

```
[myButton setEnabled:NO]
```

This will act on the answer to user clicks (and it's what you're looking for). Is your image mainly grey? Disabling the button will make the button gray, and this could make the image invisible...

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Yes, I am using setEnabled:NO and my image is not grey. It's very strange disabling the button can influence its visibility.